# Pycharm console error when I want to use remote interpreter

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, interpreter

Currently I use the remote python interpreter in my server. If I run the python file with this interpreter in Pycharm, it runs well.
However, when I ran my code with python console(using remote interpreter) in Pycharm, there was a error like this

ssh://doogiemin@192.168.0.3:22/home/doogiemin/anaconda2/bin/python /home/doogiemin/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 0 0
Couldn't connect to console process.
Process finished with exit code -1

So I checked the ~/Library/Logs/PyCharm2016.2/idea.log

2016-09-29 21:29:00,598 [2527527]   INFO - esdk.transport.JschExecProcess - Executing ssh command: cd /home/doogiemin/Documents/PycharmProjects/sshProject; env "     PYTHONIOENCODING"="UTF-8" "PYCHARM_HOSTED"="1" "PYTHONPATH"="/home/doogiemin/Documents/PycharmProjects/sshProject" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED"=     "1" /home/doogiemin/anaconda2/bin/python -u /home/doogiemin/Documents/PycharmProjects/sshProject/HelloWorld.py for doogiemin@192.168.0.3:22

I couldn't understand the error, what should I do?

Comment: happens to me as well - a bit mystery